# How to transform hover dropdown to clickable dropdown?

Tags: html, css

Sorry for me newbie question, but I'm a rooky in web-dev.

I have a code which allows me to place a hooverable elements on my website. Problem is that I want to transfer it now to clickable element - best is right click.

I tried to do it with :active option in css but it didn't work.

```
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #f9f9f9;
   min-width: 160px;
   box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   padding: 12px 16px;
   z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
   display: block;
}
```

Is there a simple way to achieve that in pure css?

Comment: You need to use jQuery for this.

Comment: You have tagged your question as `javascript` and you want a pure css solution?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, already edited.

Comment: please provide snippet of what you've tried so far

Answer (score 3):

In pure CSS you may have to use what's called [the checkbox hack](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/). Basically you use a checkbox to record whether the dropdown is open or not, and use `:checked` pseudo class to decide whether the `dropdown-content` is shown or not.

```css
#dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#dropdown:checked ~ .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
}
```

```html
<label for="dropdown">Dropdown</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="dropdown">
<div class="dropdown-content">
  And this is the content.
</div>
```

I would suggest using Javascript for this instead.

Typically, in JS, this is done by adding a class such as "active" or "open" to the dropdown component itself. Then you could modify the CSS selector to display the dropdown-content from `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content` to `.dropdown.open .dropdown-content`.

To do that, you will need to have an event listener for click (and possibly even some keyboard events such as Enter keypress) and then add the "open" or "active" class to the dropdown. Here's a snippet to show how that can be done:

```js
var dropdown = document.querySelector(".dropdown");
dropdown.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var dropdown = e.target;

  // If it has "open" class, remove it. Else add it.
  if (dropdown.classList.contains("open")) {
    dropdown.classList.remove("open");
  } else {
    dropdown.classList.add("open");
  }
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown.open .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  Let's say this is dropdown.
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    And this is the content.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does it not work? What is the problem? Did you try clicking on the dropdown?

Comment: Clicking on the element don't provide any action. I copied JS function into my JS file and changed the CSS content.

Comment: Does it work when you click "Run code snippet" here? If yes, then you might be missing something. Also, check the console to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Yes I have an error, dropdown is null. But I have class dropdown in my html code.

Comment: It is hard to diagnose the issue without looking at the code. Can you try debugging in the developer tools? Or you can create a reproducible example in JSFiddle or maybe post a separate question.

Comment: So, I tried to debbug it and it seems that the problem is that nothing is returned in document.querySelector. From where is that selector taken? From css or js file?

Comment: It means when the JS runs that element doesn't exist in DOM. Make sure that there is an element with class "dropdown" declared in HTML before the Javascript runs.

Comment: I wrapped the function in function and I called it whenever I click on the button. Error disappear but still nothing is happening.